# Can not hardcode library search path of binutils

Tags: linux, system-installation, cross-compilation

I try to build [linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter05/binutils-pass1.html) without root access, at a custom location, and within an existing CentOS installation.

I set `LFS` to an absolute path in my home directory, `LFS_TGT=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu`, and `export PATH=${LFS}/tools/bin:$PATH`

Built `binutils-2.28` with:

```
../configure --prefix=${LFS}/tools      \
             --with-sysroot=$LFS        \
             --with-lib-path=${LFS}/tools/lib \
             --target=$LFS_TGT          \
             --disable-nls              \
             --disable-werror
```

After that I symlink `${LFS}/tools/lib64` to `${LFS}/tools/lib`, installed kernel header for `linux-2-6-32-8`, `gcc-4.9.2`, and built `glibc-2.11.1`, all to the `${LFS}/tools` directory.

Then I typed `x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ld -lc`, and I get the following error:

```
x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lc
```

I `cd ${LFS}/tools/lib64` and then `x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ld libc.so` gives the following error:

```
x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find ${LFS}/tools/lib/libc.so.6 inside ${LFS}
```

I just can't understand this error. The `libc.so.6` file is at the right location.

I thought the `--with-lib-path=${LFS}/tools/lib` option for configuration of `binutils-2.28` would tell `x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ld` to look for libraries in `${LFS}/tools/lib` without having to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environmental variable. But this is not the case.

Why?

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `${LFS}/tools/lib` would make everything gives segmentation fault, including things I just built and the existing core utils of the CentOS.

---

Update:

I also tried:

```
../configure --prefix=${LFS}/tools      \
             --with-sysroot=$LFS        \
             --with-lib-path=tools/lib  \  # this is changed
             --target=$LFS_TGT          \
             --disable-nls              \
             --disable-werror
```

But those two errors still happen.

Comment: i have been trying this for 2 days, and sort of wrote my own package manager in bash because i had to keep reinstalling things. if you have an idea, i will try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and after 2 days of struggling I found the problem.
the problem is with glibc.
ld finds `libc.so` file and tries to link with it but this file is a linker script that informs th linker which files to link with.
the contents is:

```
/* GNU ld script
Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( ${LFS}/tools/lib/libc.so.6 ${LFS}/tools/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( ${LFS}/tools/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

as gcc passes `--sysroot=${LFS}` option to ld. ld adds `${LFS}` to `${LFS}/tools/lib/libc.so.6` and tries to link with it which results in the error above.

`glibc_source_dir/Makerules line 1082`:

```
install: $(inst_libdir)/libc.so
$(inst_libdir)/libc.so: $(common-objpfx)format.lds \
        $(common-objpfx)libc.so$(libc.so-version) \
        $(inst_libdir)/$(patsubst %,$(libtype.oS),\
                      $(libprefix)$(libc-name)) \
        $(+force)
        (echo '/* GNU ld script';\
 echo '   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in';\
 echo '   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */';\
 cat $<; \
 echo 'GROUP ( $(slibdir)/libc.so$(libc.so-version)' \
      '$(libdir)/$(patsubst %,$(libtype.oS),$(libprefix)$(libc-name))'\
      ' AS_NEEDED (' $(rtlddir)/$(rtld-installed-name) ') )' \
) > $@.new
mv -f $@.new $@
```

glibc's install target installs every library to `$(inst_libdir)` which is `$(DESTDIR)$(prefix)` but it uses `$(libdir)` and `$(slibdir)` when writing `libc.so` file which are reletive to `$(prefix)` not `$(DESTDIR)`.

solution:
you have to configure glibc with `--prefix=/tools` and then install it with:
`DESTDIR=${LFS} make install`

Comment: Very useful answer - I did not know libc.so was a text file! The whole linux ecosystem is quite brittle ... so much shell code logic in there, so many hardcoded assumptions ...

Comment: Thank you @sajadbanooie for this great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fist build a newer version of compiler (gcc-4.4.3 for compiling for the host architecture, instead of cross compiling) because the centos's compiler was 4.1.2 and that is too old to build glibc-2.11.1. After that, I use this new compiler to build the cross compiling tool chain in "Linux from scratch version 6.6". That version hasn't asked me to do any `sed` so far... I guess I will set up the cross compiler and then use it to build newer versions of gcc and glibc.